# Form Action and Javascript Conflict

Tags: javascript, forms

need some help on this one...

I'm working with a form and a script to show alert...

I'm using this code to achieve this and its working fine:

```
        <input id="autocomplete" class="input_message" type="text" name="message" autocomplete="off" placeholder="...type your message" ><br/>                              
        <input id="input_send" class="input_send" type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
```

but if i put some form method, the alert on my script is not working..

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input id="autocomplete" class="input_message" type="text" name="message" autocomplete="off" placeholder="...type your message" ><br/>                              
        <input id="input_send" class="input_send" type="submit" name="send" value="SEND">
    </form>
```

here is my script:

```
<div id="alertbox">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input_send').click(function(){
        var post = $('#autocomplete').val();
        if(post==""){   
            alert('Enter Message Please');  
        }else{
        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="./loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">sending</span>');
        var datasend = "alert";
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'./includes/alerts.php',
            data:datasend,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg__){    
                $('#autocomplete').val('');
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#alertbox').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg__);
                $('#alerts').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');   
            }
        });
        }
    })          
});
</script>
</div>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: It's probably working exactly as it should, when you click a submit button in a form, the form is submitted, reloading the page ?

Comment: yah but my alert script didn't show-up..

Comment: You should not act upon the click event of the button. You should handle the submit event on the form. You are also able to cancle the submission in there.

Comment: @RowellCasañaCeleste Yes, because the button has not really been clicked. The form is being processed for submission instead.

Comment: ok i get it.. but how can i able to trigger the button script upon process of submission?

Answer (score 0):

the submit button post the form to the server, and the page is reloaded;

you can add return false;, 
after the ajax function, then is not sends to the server

Answer (score 0):

need to prevent form submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#input_send').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();//here
        var post = $('#autocomplete').val();
        if(post==""){   
            alert('Enter Message Please');  
        }else{
        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="./loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">sending</span>');
        var datasend = "alert";
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'./includes/alerts.php',
            data:datasend,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg__){    
                $('#autocomplete').val('');
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#alertbox').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg__);
                $('#alerts').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');   
            }
        });
        }
    })          
});
```

Or change the type of the `#input_send`from `submit` to `button` so that the form submission will not be triggered

```
<input id="input_send" class="input_send" type="button" name="send" value="SEND">
```

Comment: thanks but if i change the #input_send from submit to button.. the alert is working but on the other side.. my form is not working and unable to get some data..